# SyncFusion SfChart won't render in iOS simulator (white screen) but shows in Visual Studio Preview?

Tags: xamarin, syncfusion

Today I'm playing around with my new Community License of SFCharts. I've created a simple chart solution in Xamarin from a tutorial, and by all accounts it works fine. I'm authoring it in Visual Studio 2019 (Mac) although I do a fair bit of work on the PC too.

When I view the project in Preview mode in Visual Studio it appears to render just fine (see screenshot).
![1]: https://ibb.co/Dtrf0y1 "Preview"

When I launch it in Android it appears to render just fine (see screenshot).
![2]: https://ibb.co/4mdzRQ7 "Android"

But when I launch it in the iOS simulator, I get nothing but a white screen. Not even headlines or anything, just white.
![3]: https://ibb.co/YQdcXM8 "iOS"

Any thoughts as to where this might be going wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Xamarin does not load the renderer assemblies in iOS and macOS projects. So, in order to solve this issue, manually load it by calling a static Init method of SfChartRenderer class in the respective projects as mentioned below.

**iOS Project**

Call Init method of SfChartRenderer in FinishedLaunching overridden method of AppDelegate class in iOS Project as shown below.

```
 public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
 { 
   ... 
   Syncfusion.SfChart.XForms.iOS.Renderers.SfChartRenderer.Init(); 
   ... 
 }
```

**macOS Project**

Call Init method of SfChartRenderer in DidFinishLaunching overridden method of AppDelegate class in macOS Project as shown below.

```
 public override void DidFinishLaunching(NSNotification notification)
 { 
   ... 
   Syncfusion.SfChart.XForms.MacOS.SfChartRenderer.Init(); 
   ... 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have read a little deeper into the documentation, but this suggestion worked and solved my problem. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this code in AppDelegate.cs class?

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options) 
{ 
   … 

 global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

 **Syncfusion.SfChart.XForms.iOS.Renderers.SfChartRenderer.Init();**

 LoadApplication(new App()); 
 …
}
```

Please refer this link:
[https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sfchart/getting-started#launching-the-application-on-each-platform-with-chart]